# Dockerfile - Access volume outside container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a container to host my flask server on. However I want to be able to access some/all files outside of the container in case that the container itself gets deleted. The most important thing is the database.

How can I access for example `/web/server/data` outside in a directory lets say /mnt/temp_docker_dir

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine3.12

VOLUME /web/config
VOLUME /web/server/data
WORKDIR /web

ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 5000
ENV SECRET_KEY temp
ENV DEBUG FALSE

RUN apk add -U --no-cache gcc build-base linux-headers ca-certificates python3-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev libxslt-dev

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /server/market.dbsystem.db /web/server/data/

COPY server /web/server/

COPY manage.py /web
 
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./manage.py", "create_db"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./manage.py","runserver","--host","0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Have a look on https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/

Comment: @jlandercy Based on what you sent I found something that gave the following: "bind  /mnt/temp_docker_dir /data   true rprivate." However I cant see any content in that directory. In this case the database..

Comment: You've done half of the work. All you need to do now is add a volume when you do the `docker run` command. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Also have a read of this. https://success.docker.com/article/different-types-of-volumes.
There is a difference between a `named volume` and an `anonymous volume`. You can also use `docker container inspect my_cont` and check what volume is associated with the running container.

Comment: @JordanSimba So named/anonymous volumes could be the cause of the problem? Currently I try to run it with: docker run --name test_server -p 5000:5000 -v /mnt/temp_docker_dir:/web/server/data rp but can still not see the data within the container.

Comment: I didn't know if you were running with `-v` option, the data 'should be being written'...
Are you sure the container is actually producing data?
Is the data accessible to you or is the app writing the data as root and you can't see it on the host?

Comment: @JordanSimba After some testing I can see that I can access the container folder /web/server/data. However it seems like the copy to /web/server/data/ does not create the requested database which is does if -v is not applied.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read the docker file closely enough. If you define /web/server/data as a volume in the dockerfile no changes made at build time will persist so whatever COPY does is immediately lost ... I would suggest you remove the VOLUME /web anything and simply mount at runtime

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the volume directives In the dockerfile and testing without them

Comment: @JordanSimba It seems to be working. I'm starting to think that python has some kind of bug in it that the manage.py create_db doesnt work as intented which makes the creation of a db fail.

Comment: Did you remove the volume directives and it started working? A quick check would be to do RUN ls -la immediately after your COPY of the db data. I don't think it's a python issue ... At least I hope not ... I had a strange encounter with something similar a while ago...

Comment: @JordanSimba Yes I did, and it seemed to fix it. I will try to investigate a bit more and see if I can understand why it happens. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries! Good luck!